# React-virtualized table sorting issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, react-virtualized

I'm using react-virtualized table and I have some issues regarding sorting.

First of all, some columns that contain numbers need numeric sorting, for example I want this [1, 200, 10500, 29000] and not this [1, 10500, 200, 29000]. How can I pass numeric sorting to certain columns?

Another issue about sorting is this:

```
Bucharest
Bucharest
Bucuresti
IASI
Oradea
ARAD
BRASOV
BUCHAREST
BUCHAREST
Bucharest
Bucharest
Bucharest
```

What's going on here? First and last 'Bucharest' strings are identical.

Here is my code:

```
import { items } from 'model/component-props';
import _ from 'lodash';

class Items extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        sortBy: 'No',
        sortDirection: 'ASC',
    }
}

sort = ({sortBy, sortDirection}) => {
  console.log({sortBy, sortDirection})
  this.setState({
    sortBy,
    sortDirection,
  })
}

render(){
  const { items } = this.props;
  const simplifiedData = items && _.get(items, ['Soap:Envelope', 'Soap:Body', 'ReadMultiple_Result', 'ReadMultiple_Result', 'ItemList']);
  const beautifiedData = _.map(simplifiedData, simple => _.reduce(simple, (r, value, key) => ({
      ...r,
      [key]: value['_text']
    }), {}));
  const searchKeysList = ['No', 'Description', 'TranslateDescr', 'Inventory', 'Special_Weight', 'Composition', 'Width', 'Unit_Price'];
  const filteredData = beautifiedData && beautifiedData.filter(obj =>
      _.has(obj, itemSearchKey) && _.includes(obj[itemSearchKey].toLowerCase(), itemSearchTerm.toLowerCase()));

  const tempList = _.sortBy([...filteredData], d => d[this.state.sortBy]);
  const list = this.state.sortDirection === 'DESC' ? tempList.reverse() : tempList;


  return (
    <div>
     <Table 
       style={{paddingTop: '20px'}}
       rowStyle={{border: '0.5px dashed grey'}}
       width={1400}
       height={400}
       headerHeight={35}
       rowHeight={30}
       rowCount={list.length}
       rowGetter={({ index }) => list[index]}
       sortBy={this.state.sortBy}
       sortDirection={this.state.sortDirection}
       sort={this.sort}
       onRowClick={({ rowData }) => this.onItemCardClick(rowData.No)}
    >
       <Column
         label={content[langProp].ID}
         dataKey= 'No'
         width={150}
       />
       <Column
         style={{textAlign: 'right'}}
         label={content[langProp].Inventory}
         headerStyle={{textAlign: 'right'}}
         cellDataGetter={({ rowData }) => parseFloat(rowData.Inventory).toFixed(2).toString().replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",")}
          dataKey='Inventory'
          disableSort='true'
          width={200}
        />
        <Column
          label={content[langProp].City}
          dataKey='City'
          width={200}
        />
     </Table>
   </div>
);
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where is `_.sortBy()` coming from? Are you using undersccore.js? If so then what is `d => d[this.state.sortBy]` supposed to be doing? It'll be easier to debug the issue if the nature of `filteredData` is available.

Comment: @ManavM Thanks for your answer, I edited my question.

Comment: I think you can create a function to check the type of the field you want to sort and sort accordingly the type. Maybe regex can help to detect if it is number or string

Comment: @Morgana, It would be better to have JSFiddle or codesandbox demo link so that it 
 will be easier for anyone to debug and give u the solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you run

```
var users = [
  { 'age': 315 },
  { 'age': 34 }
];

var result = _.sortBy(users, u => u.age);
```

You'll find that it returns `{age: 34}, {age: 315}]`, so your numeric issue should not exist...I would guess that the value is actually being stored as a string in which case you can run a regex to check if the string is supposed to be a number in your iteratee like this

```
var result = _.sortBy(data, d => {
    const str = d[this.state.sortBy];
    var patt = new RegExp("^\d+$");
    if(patt.test(str)) {
      return Number.parseInt(str)
    }
    return str;
  }
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately I'm not sure what is causing the issue with the Bucharest thing. I would need a sample of the original and the resultant array  to see what's going on. That is..`console.log([...filteredData], tempList);`

Comment: Thank you for your answer and your time. Although regExp did not solve the numeric sorting problem, your answer made me started thinking of another approach to this.